# Delete all fields having value 5x lower then top field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (`prices`) with two fields, `code` (char) and price (decimal).
I need to find all fields with same code, having price 5x lower then top price. E.g, in this case:

```
id   code   price
1    1001   10
2    1001   101
3    1001   40
4    1002   10
5    1002   122
6    1002   50
```

I need to delete fields with id 1 and 4. I'm trying smth. like this:

```
DELETE FROM `prices` WHERE `code` IN (SELECT `code` FROM `prices` sa WHERE `code` IN (SELECT `code` FROM `prices` WHERE `price`>sa.`price`*5) and sa.code=prices.code);
```

But I'm not sure this is right way.
The next task is to delete all fields, 3x lower then two top fields. So, if we have minimum two fields higher than 100, we need to delete all fields lower than 25.

Comment: I would stick to the first question.  Otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: 3x lower than 100 is 25?

Comment: Sorry, 3x lower or less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `join` and aggregation:

```
delete p
    from prices p join
         (select p.code, max(price) as max_price
          from prices p
          group by p.code
         ) pp
         on pp.code = p.code and pp.price < p.price * 0.2;
```

Comment: select *
    from prices p join
         (select p.code, max(price) as max_price, price
          from prices p
          group by p.code
         ) pp
         on pp.code = p.code and pp.price < p.price * 0.2;   Thank you, added ", price" after "as max_price" and all is ok.

Comment: Can you help me with the second part of this question?

Comment: Ask another question.